# Kivy ScrollView - Not Scrolling

Tags: python, kivy

Looks like a common problem people have with Kivy. I've already checked other questions for the same problem here on SO but no luck.

I have a container **BoxLayout**:

```
class Cnt(BoxLayout):
    pass
```

In the **.kv** file I've got something like this:

```
<Cnt>:
    orientation: 'vertical'
    ScrollView:
        size_hint: (1, .9)
        StackLayout:
            padding: 5
            size_hint_y: None
            id: content_layout
            minimum_height: self.height
            ARow:
            ARow:
            ARow:
            ARow:
            ARow:
            ARow:
            ARow:
            ARow:
            ARow:
            ARow:
            ARow:
            ARow:
            ARow:
            ARow:
            ARow:
    BoxLayout:
        size_hint: (1, .1)
        Label:
            text: 'A'
```

**ARow** is a **BoxLayout** with a **CheckBox** and a **Label**. It has:

```
size_hint: (1, None)
height: 40
```

As far as I understand these are the only two important things that could do something to the scrolling.

**minimum_height: self.height** is the same as if I would bind the minimum_height and height of the **StackLayout** in Python code if I understood it right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change

```
minimum_height: self.height
```

to

```
height: self.minimum_height
```

The `minimum_height` is what's calculated as needed for all the children. You want the actual height to be equal to the minimum height, even if it's larger than the parent's height (for scrolling, this is exactly what you want).