# Kivy grid layout's minimum_height is 0

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy

So I am new to kivy and I am trying to make list of buttons scrollable. The thing is that i couldn't get scrollview to work, then I stumbled upon [Kivy ScrollView - Not Scrolling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32445341/kivy-scrollview-not-scrolling). When I added it to my code it still didn't work. Then I tried printing the minimum_height and it always printed 0 no matter how many buttons there were...

This is the code(it is really badly wrote but this is just for testing purposes, I will probably rewrite it when I manage the scrolling):

```py
    def on_pre_enter(self, *args):
        mainLayout = RelativeLayout()
        self.add_widget(mainLayout)
        scroll = ScrollView(do_scroll_x = False)
        infoLayout = GridLayout(cols = 1, size_hint = (0.5, None), pos_hint={"top":0.8,"center_x":0.5})
        mainLayout.add_widget(scroll)
        scroll.add_widget(infoLayout)

        InfoWidgetButton = Button(text='Hello world', font_size=14, size_hint=(0.5, None), height = 30, pos_hint={"top":0.8,"center_x":0.5}, on_release= lambda x:self.buttonPress(infoLayout))
        infoLayout.add_widget(InfoWidgetButton)
        InfoWidgetButton = Button(text='Hello world', font_size=14, size_hint=(0.5, None), height=30,
                                  pos_hint={"top": 0.8, "center_x": 0.5},
                                  on_release=lambda x: self.buttonPress(infoLayout))
        infoLayout.add_widget(InfoWidgetButton)
        InfoWidgetButton = Button(text='Hello world', font_size=14, size_hint=(0.5, None), height=30,
                                  pos_hint={"top": 0.8, "center_x": 0.5},
                                  on_release=lambda x: self.buttonPress(infoLayout))
        infoLayout.add_widget(InfoWidgetButton)
        InfoWidgetButton = Button(text='Hello world', font_size=14, size_hint=(0.5, None), height=30,
                                  pos_hint={"top": 0.8, "center_x": 0.5},
                                  on_release=lambda x: self.buttonPress(infoLayout))
        infoLayout.add_widget(InfoWidgetButton)
        InfoWidgetButton = Button(text='Hello world', font_size=14, size_hint=(0.5, None), height=30,
                                  pos_hint={"top": 0.8, "center_x": 0.5},
                                  on_release=lambda x: self.buttonPress(infoLayout))
        infoLayout.add_widget(InfoWidgetButton)
        InfoWidgetButton = Button(text='Hello world', font_size=14, size_hint=(0.5, None), height=30,
                                  pos_hint={"top": 0.8, "center_x": 0.5},
                                  on_release=lambda x: self.buttonPress(infoLayout))
        infoLayout.add_widget(InfoWidgetButton)
        InfoWidgetButton = Button(text='Hello world', font_size=14, size_hint=(0.5, None), height=30,
                                  pos_hint={"top": 0.8, "center_x": 0.5},
                                  on_release=lambda x: self.buttonPress(infoLayout))
        infoLayout.add_widget(InfoWidgetButton)
        infoLayout.height = infoLayout.minimum_height
        print(infoLayout.minimum_height)
```

Comment: It's 0 at the point you print it, it probably isn't 0 on the next frame after all the callbacks have run

Answer (score 1):

A guy answered my question on reddit:
https://www.reddit.com/r/kivy/comments/irats0/kivy_grid_layouts_minimum_height_is_0/